# How can I control which options are displayed in each of my two <select> elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following segment of code:

```
<p>
   <label>Dual Select</label>
    <span id="dualselect" class="dualselect">
        <select name="select3" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value="">Selection One</option>
            <option value="">Selection Two</option>
            <option value="">Selection Three</option>
            <option value="">Selection Four</option>
            <option value="">Selection Five</option>
            <option value="">Selection Six</option>
            <option value="">Selection Seven</option>
            <option value="">Selection Eight</option>
        </select>
        <span class="ds_arrow">
            <span class="arrow ds_prev">&laquo;</span>
            <span class="arrow ds_next">&raquo;</span>
        </span>
        <select name="select4" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
```

It renders in the browser like this:
[image: view html code produces]

(I am using asp.net mvc4 to display this code.)

How do I go about being able to specify which option goes on which side initially?

For example, I want all of the possible options on the left, and I want all of the options that I am registered for on the right.

**Edit:** I tried specifying this in the HTML (i.e. by putting all of the options that I am registered for in the second `<select>`), but I still got the same rendering when I loaded the page.

There are a few jQuery files included at the top of the page that came with the theme. I think the following jQuery deals with this control:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//dual box
var db = jQuery('#dualselect').find('.ds_arrow .arrow');    //get arrows of dual select
var sel1 = jQuery('#dualselect select:first-child');        //get first select element
var sel2 = jQuery('#dualselect select:last-child');         //get second select element

sel2.empty(); //empty it first from dom.

db.click(function(){
    var t = (jQuery(this).hasClass('ds_prev'))? 0 : 1;  // 0 if arrow prev otherwise arrow next
    if(t) {
        sel1.find('option').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).is(':selected')) {
                jQuery(this).attr('selected',false);
                var op = sel2.find('option:first-child');
                sel2.append(jQuery(this));
            }
        }); 
    } else {
        sel2.find('option').each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).is(':selected')) {
                jQuery(this).attr('selected',false);
                sel1.append(jQuery(this));
            }
        });     
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you want on the left should go in the first `<select>` element (`name="select3"`).

The options you want on the right should go in the second `<select>` element (`name="select4"`).

Basically, exactly how it is now.

**Edit:** ah - the following line in your jQuery file is emptying the second `<select>` element on document ready for some reason.

```
sel2.empty();
```

---

For reference, the `<label>` element is being used incorrectly. Each `<label>` is meant to have one form element (referenced by `id` in the `<label>`'s `for` attribute) that it labels, otherwise it's a bit useless (see http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-label-element).

To label multiple form elements (like your two `<select>`s), you wrap them in a `<fieldset>` element, and use the `<legend>` element inside the fieldset.

Comment: Omw are you serious? I feel like an utter noob. Cant believe i didn't see that.

Comment: @Zapnologica: Srsly. Naw don't worry, "obvious" stuff isn't obvious when you're not familiar with the context.

Comment: I for some reason still seem to be having a problem:

Its not displaying them on the site.  but here is the source code which I found by right clicking view source code. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Zapnologica: there'll be some other code causing the behaviour you're seeing (possibly jQuery) - using just your supplied HTML, I see the options where they're meant to be: http://jsfiddle.net/E48QK/ Maybe you could build the page up from scratch to identify which code is causing that behaviour.

Comment: See Updated Post: I have found the jQuery file responsible and posted it above. What could be my issue?

Comment: @Zapnologica: ah yes. `sel2.empty();` is emptying the second `<select>` on document ready.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33570/discussion-between-zapnologica-and-paul-d-waite)